# Configuring CUPS PDF writer for PDF/A output?

Tags: pdf, cups

Can the PDF pseudo-printer in CUPS be configured to emit [PDF/A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) files? If so, how to do it?

I'm using CUPS 1.5.3-5 and CUPS-PDF 2.6.1-6 as provided by Debian Wheezy/7.0.

Despite [CUPS PDF Format - Documentation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/spec-pdf.html) claiming that "CUPS PDF files (application/vnd.cups-pdf) are device-dependent PDF/A files that contain a job ticket information.", at least [one online validator](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx) claims that a to-PDF print of itself from the web browser "does not conform to PDF/A".

Comment: What are PDF/A files? Are they just regular PDF files?

Comment: @slm Almost. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A In short, it is a subset of the PDF format designed specifically for long-term archival.

Answer (score 1):

I found this extremely detailed tutorial which discusses how to create PDF/A files. Looking at the tutorial I would assume that a cups printer could be configured to expose a script which could run documents submitted to CUPS through said script producing PDF/A files as discussed in that tutorial.

- [Linux, OCR and PDF: Scan to PDF/A](http://blog.konradvoelkel.de/2013/03/scan-to-pdfa/)

This StackOverflow Q&A covers how to configure CUPS.

- [Programming a Filter/Backend to 'Print to PDF' with CUPS from any Mac OS X application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192396/programming-a-filter-backend-to-print-to-pdf-with-cups-from-any-mac-os-x-appli)

#### References

- [Printing/Developer Tools - KDE Wiki](http://community.kde.org/Printing/Developer_Tools#.272dir.27_CUPS_backend_script_.28Bash_code.29)

Comment: I don't see how either of these links answer my question, but maybe I am missing something obvious? I don't want to print to paper, then scan, then OCR, just to get a PDF/A file (especially since I don't even have a color printer); I want to be able to print to PDF/A directly, through the CUPS pseudo-printer which is already there and produces PDF output (also preserving some semantic info), just not PDF/A. [One of the answers to the SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11194723/486504) seems somewhat relevant, but even it doesn't seem to say anything about how to make CUPS-PDF emit PDF/A.

Comment: Please note that although this question is similar to [my other one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79516/2465), they are distinct. This one deals with printing directly to PDF/A, the other question deals with already-existing PDF files.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I deleted my answer on the other one, I had them open in 2 tabs in Chrome and thought they were the same question.

Comment: The first link shows how to generate a PDF/A file. That method can be rolled into a script which can be called by cups as a pre-filter, that's the general idea anyway.

Comment: This [link shows 2 scripts (2file & 2dir)](http://community.kde.org/Printing/Developer_Tools#.272dir.27_CUPS_backend_script_.28Bash_code.29) which can run when a job is printed to a particular printer in cups, the script will run and put the results to a directory or a particular file.