# Converting PDF to PDF/A?

Tags: pdf

Given a PDF of random origin, how do I, on Linux:

- confirm whether it is in [PDF/A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) format already?
- if it is not in PDF/A format, convert it to PDF/A with a minimum loss of fidelity?

I am aware that the conversion may cause loss of exotic elements of the document, but let's assume that the ability to open the document at all in a relatively far future is more important than such spiffy features (which might not be available/readable at such a time anyway). I would rather be able to visually confirm the accuracy of the conversion when I can trivially view the documents side by side than risk not being able to open the original file.

Answer (score 10):

#### Identification

I found this tool which looks to be what you can use to identify PDF/A files. It's called [DROID (Digital Record and Object Identification)](http://digital-preservation.github.io/droid/). It's Java based and can be run from a GUI or the command-line.

*excerpt*

> DROID is a software tool developed by The National Archives to perform
> automated batch identification of file formats. Developed by its
> Digital Preservation Department as part of its broader digital
> preservation activities, DROID is designed to meet the fundamental
> requirement of any digital repository to be able to identify the
> precise format of all stored digital objects, and to link that
> identification to a central registry of technical information about
> that format and its dependencies.

Given it's sponsored by the National Archives I would assume it's the right tool for doing this, given the intended purpose of the PDF/A format. Also the project is open source and the [code is available on Github](https://github.com/digital-preservation/droid) as well as packaged in binary form from the [National Archives website](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/information-management/projects-and-work/droid.htm).

#### Validation & Conversion

If you're looking for a tool to perform validation & conversion I believe [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) can do this. PDFBox lists PDF/A validation right on the front page of their website. It's another Java application 8-).

*excerpt from website*

> PDF/A Validation
> Validate PDFs against the PDF/A ISO standard.

Under the [command line tools section](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/) on the left of their main page the show the following usage for the tool:

```
$ java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar org.apache.pdfbox.ConvertColorspace [OPTIONS] <inputfile> <outputfile>
```

[veraPDF](http://verapdf.org) is another tool capable of validating PDF/A; it is part of the Open Preservation Foundation’s reference tool set. It’s also a Java application.

#### Conversion

For just doing conversion I found this method from a blog post titled: [Free way to convert an existing PDF to PDF/A](http://thisthatisnot.blogspot.com/2010/04/free-way-to-convert-existing-pdf-to.html), that uses the following tools:

- Ghostscript 8.64 Only.
- PDFBox 0.7.3
- pdfmarks ( file to supply additional meta data)
- PDFA_def.ps
- USWebCoatedSWOP.icc

With the above in place you use the following command:

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOSAFER     \
-dPDFA -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK       \
-sOutputFile=Out_PDFA.pdf PDFA_def.ps pdfmarks IN_PDF.pdf
```

It isn't without it's warts. The article discusses one of them, fixing the print flags on hyperlinks being one of them. The article provides a Java application that you can use to fix these:

```
$ java FixPrintFlag Out_PDFA.pdf New_verifiablePDFA.pdf
```

It's not pretty but appears to be workable. See the [article](http://thisthatisnot.blogspot.com/2010/04/free-way-to-convert-existing-pdf-to.html) for more details.

#### save as PDF/A via cups

cups allow to "print to pdf file". The command used is in `/etc/cups/cups.conf`. There you will find a variable `GSCall` which have the arguments used to call the `gs` binary to create the pdf file. Add `-dPDFA` before the `-dNOPAUSE` parameter, and now all your 'print as pdf' files from all applications on linux will magically be PDF/A!

#### References

- [PDF to PDF-A conversion - wiki.opf-labs.org](http://wiki.opf-labs.org/display/REQ/PDF+to+PDF-A+conversion)
- [arch linux cups configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CUPS#Archival_PDF/A)

Comment: I'll have to give this a try - it looks awfully promising. With a little fiddling it might even be possible to integrate this into the CUPS-PDF printer; there are settings in /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf that look promising for that purpose. Thanks for taking the time! Not really up to testing it right now but I'll get back to this (hopefully tomorrow).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - thanks for the question. I'd never heard of the PDF/A format before and we have a need for this exact thing at work. So you helped me look like a genius for knowing about this stuff now 8-).

Comment: What's `pdfmarks`?

Comment: @AndrewMacFie -  https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfmark_reference.pdf

Answer (score 9):

Here is a bash command line script doing just that:

```
#!/bin/bash

pdf_input=$1
ps_output=${pdf_input%.*}.ps
pdfa_output=${pdf_input%.*}_a.pdf
pdftops ${pdf_input} ${ps_output}

gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=${pdfa_output} ${ps_output}
```

Save it in a file called pdf2pdfa.sh that is in your path, then call it like this:

pdf2pdfa.sh input.pdf

It will create input_a.pdf.

Comment: (1) Please explain what this does.  (2) What is `input`? I see `pdf_input`, but what is `input`?  (3) You should always quote shell variables unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thx, works well. Did anyone got a similar notice?

`Use of -dUseCIEColor detected!
Since the release of version 9.11 of Ghostscript we recommend you do not set
-dUseCIEColor with the pdfwrite/ps2write device family.`

Answer (score 3):

For file identification, the command `file` is often helpful. It'll look your file for magic numbers, file identifiers, encoding information, etc. to give any helpful information it can.

In the particular case of PDF files, the utilitary `pdfinfo` is specially useful. In my case, a Gentoo distribution, it's packaged with `poppler`, a PDF rendering library.

Comment: `pdfinfo -meta` and looking at `xmpmeta/RDF/Description/conformance` seems to say whether the PDF is PDF/A (that node is `A`) or not (the node doesn't exist or has some other value). It's a start!

Answer (score 0):

The [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/ocrmypdf/OCRmyPDF) tool can convert to PDF/A. In fact, that's part of its [default behavior](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#add-an-ocr-layer-and-convert-to-pdf-a). But it also allows [disabling the OCR step](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#don-t-actually-ocr-my-pdf) while retaining its image processing features and the PDF/A conversion:

```
ocrmypdf --tesseract-timeout=0 input.pdf output.pdf
```